# Check if a FirebaseUser has a 'real' ProfilePicture set

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using `FirebaseAuth` and the possibility to sign in using a Google account.

As you are all aware your Google Account either has a picture attached or has the little colored circle with the first letter of your name in it.

My problem is the following: When I retrieve the `FirebaseUser` object in my app, I would like to check if the user had an own profile picture attached to his google account. I thought I can simply
check:

`if (firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null)`

As it turns out if you had no picture of the colored letter picture it still is attached as "Account Picture" and getPhotoUrl points to that letter image.

Does anyone know if there is a possibility to check if the image is "real" or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement:

```
if (firebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null)
```

Will always evaluates to false, since that little colored circle with the first letter of the name on it is always present. So not having a photo attached to the Google account doesn't mean that your photo URL is null. It's not, as it points to that colored circle image.

> Does anyone know if there is a possibility to check if the image is "real" or not?

Yes, there is a possibility to check that. We are very fortunate that Firebase can do that. In Android, you can detect faces with ML Kit:

- https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android

In this way, you can check if a picture is containing a real face or not.

Comment: Thank you. Never imagined that I have to include that much overhead. I guess I will not adapt this. The only intention I had was using my own "no profile picture" images instead of google ones. But face recognition for that purpose seems a bit too much. Thank you for your answer